# SQL return values if row count > X

Tags: sql

```
DECLARE @sql_string varchar(7000)
set @sql_string = (select top 1 statement from queries where name = 'report name')

EXECUTE (@sql_string)
```

@sql_string is holding another SQL statement. This query works for me. It returns all the values from the query from the statement on the queries table.  From this, I need to figure out how to only return the results IF the number of rows returned exceeds a threshold (for my particular case, 25). Else return nothing. I can't quite figure out how to get this conditional statement to work.

Much appreciated for any direction on this.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the queries return the same columns, you could simply store the data in a temporary table or table variable and then use logic such as:

```
select t.*
from @t t
where (select count(*) from @t) > 25;
```

An alternative is to try constructing a new query from the existing query.  I don't recommend trying to parse the existing string, if you can avoid that. Assuming that the query does not use CTEs or have an `ORDER BY` clause, for instance, something like this should work:

```
set @sql = '
with q as (
      ' + @sql + '
     )
select q.*
from q
where (select count(*) from q) > 25
';
```

Answer (score 0):

That did the trick @Gordon. Here was my final:

```
DECLARE @report_name varchar(100)
DECLARE @sql_string varchar(7000)
DECLARE @sql varchar(7000)
DECLARE @days int

set @report_name = 'Complex Pass Failed within 1 day'
set @days = 5

set @sql_string = (select top 1 statement from queries where name = @report_name )
set @sql = 'with q as (' + @sql_string + ') select q.* from q where (select count(*) from q) > ' + convert(varchar(100), @days)

EXECUTE (@sql)
```

Worked with 2 nuances.

1. The SQL returned could not include an end ";" charicter
2. The statement cannot include an "order by" statement